# На каком языке должна быть межъязыковая связь?

Tags: обсуждение

Собственно, я везде использовал язык текущего сайта, но вчера [Rob](//meta.stackoverflow.com/users/563532/rob) на metaSO [написал](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323148/should-i-encourage-people-to-use-the-localized-versions-of-so#comment344814_323148):

> @Qwertiy It seems to me that the translation links are in the wrong languages. People who don't speak Russian won't understand they're being told there's an English translation, and vice-versa ;)

Мне кажется, что если человек попал на сайт из поисковика, то язык он знает достаточно, чтобы понять ссылку. Если же он перешел по аналогичной ссылке куда-то, где не понимает язык (хотя код посмотреть может), то эта ссылка ему и не особо нужна.

Да и как-то недружелюбно по отношению к другим обитателям сайта включать в вопрос ссылку на чужом языке.

Как же правильно? Может вообще ставить ссылку на обоих языках через слеш?

Comment: А что именно он называет `the translation links`? Наверное, я не очень знаю английский, поэтому суть его претензий от меня ускользает.

Comment: @avp, думаю, PS в [подобных вопросах](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/524332/178988). Хотя тоже не очень уверен.

Comment: Ага, речь о *переведенных темах* и ссылках на копию/оригинал на другом языке. Ну, может он и прав. Или как Вы предложили -- на обоих языках.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тот, кто не говорит по-русски, не сможет понять не только межязыковую ссылку на русском - но и текст вопроса. А значит, он просто не зайдет на эту страницу.

Такие ссылки делаются для тех, кто знает **оба** языка. А потому для понимания не важно, на каком языке они написаны.

Поэтому, я считаю, к ним надо также применять общие правила сайта - писать их на языке сайта.

Comment: Вопрос лишь в том, на каком уровне человек владеет языком. Поэтому смысл в замечании Rob-а есть.

Answer (score 4):

На английском Stack Overflow, основной текст комментария должен быть на английском, но название сайта [Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com) содержит кириллицу, которую переводить не надо.

Поэтому даже если человек не достаточно английский понимает, чтобы комментарий перевести—одно название сайта само по себе уже достаточной подсказкой является (даже если по ссылке не переходить).

Например, если зайти на [All Sites - Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions), то название японского Stack Overflow приведено как [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) (без перевода на английский).